# How to extract elements from 4 lists in scala?

Tags: scala

```
case class TargetClass(key: Any, value: Number, lowerBound: Double, upperBound: Double)

val keys: List[Any] = List("key1", "key2", "key3")
val values: List[Number] = List(1,2,3);
val lowerBounds: List[Double] = List(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)
val upperBounds: List[Double] = List(0.5, 0.6, 0.7)
```

Now I want to construct a `List[TargetClass]` to hold the 4 lists. Does anyone know how to do it efficiently? Is using for-loop to add elements one by one very inefficient?

I tried to use `zipped`, but it seems that this only applies for combining up to 3 lists.

Thank you very much!

Comment: By the way, please fix your syntax for lists. The `{...}` don't work, you have to use `List ( ... )` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach:

```
keys.zipWithIndex.map {
  case (item,i)=> TargetClass(item,values(i),lowerBounds(i),upperBounds(i))
}
```

You may want to consider using the `lift` method to deal with case of lists being of unequal lengths (and thereby provide a default if keys is longer than any of the lists?)

I realise this doesn't address your question of efficiency. You could fairly easily run some tests on different approaches.

Comment: Unfortunately of the options presented, this is the most inefficient :| Running some basic tests on some of the answers, and in order of fastest to slowest, I found: 1) zip-zip-zip-map (@dk14 and @prashant); closely followed by 2) transpose-map (@srgfed01); then small gap to 3) for-transpose-yield (@The-Archetypal-Paul) followed at some distance by (4) zipWithIndex. Interesting!

Comment: @wwkudu Thanks for taking the time to do the analysis.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply zipped to the first two lists, to the last two lists, then to the results of the previous zips, then map to your class, like so:

```
val z12 = (keys, values).zipped
val z34 = (lowerBounds, upperBounds).zipped

val z1234 = (z12.toList, z34.toList).zipped

val targs = z1234.map { case ((k,v),(l,u)) => TargetClass(k,v,l,u) }

// targs = List(TargetClass(key1,1,0.1,0.5), TargetClass(key2,2,0.2,0.6), TargetClass(key3,3,0.3,0.7))
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice if `.transpose` worked on a Tuple of Lists.

```
for (List(k, v:Number, l:Double, u:Double) <- 
       List(keys, values, lowerBounds, upperBounds).transpose)
  yield TargetClass(k,v,l,u)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
keys zip values zip lowerBounds zip upperBounds map {
  case (((k, v), l), u) => TargetClass(k, v, l, u) 
}
```

Example:

```
scala> val zipped = keys zip values zip lowerBounds zip upperBounds
zipped: List[(((Any, Number), Double), Double)] = List((((key1,1),0.1),0.5), (((key2,2),0.2),0.6), (((key3,3),0.3),0.7))

scala> zipped map { case (((k, v), l), u) => TargetClass(k, v, l, u) }
res6: List[TargetClass] = List(TargetClass(key1,1,0.1,0.5), TargetClass(key2,2,0.2,0.6), TargetClass(key3,3,0.3,0.7))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think no matter what you use from an efficiency point of view, you will have to traverse the lists individually. The only question is,  do you do it OR for the  sake of readability, you use Scala idioms and let Scala do the dirty work *for* you :) ?

Other approaches are not necessarily more efficient. You can change the order of zipping and the order of assembling the return value of the `map` function as you like.

Here is a more **functional** way <s>but I am ***not*** sure it will be more efficient</s>. See comments on @wwkudu (zip with index) answer

```
 val res1 = keys zip lowerBounds zip values zip upperBounds
 res1.map { 
    x=> (x._1._1._1,x._1._1._2, x._1._2, x._2)
    //Of course, you can return an instance of TargetClass 
    //here instead of the touple I am returning.
 }
```

I am curious, why do you need a "TargetClass"? Will a touple work?

Comment: A tuple works, but I think a TagetClass is much more readable. I don't want there to be many '_1' '_3's in my code since this will be read by others.